# Alternative to Struts-Menu for menus in Struts 2.X application

Tags: java, software-development, menu

I am currently using Struts-Menu to handle my menu needs for my Struts 2 J2EE application. It is not necessarily a package I wish to work with I have found by playing around with it. So what is an alternative to this package?

I immediately flocked to Struts-Menu because I saw a fair amount of web search traffic pointing to it, including those who use Struts2. What I am worried about is difficulty in the future of making it work with other packages, given its 2007 last update and the extra tap dance I had do to make it work with my configuration. It seems too fragile at this point for my taste.

I have several different menus in my app, but the one I am specifically addressing at the present is like this: The top level menu drops down upon mouse hover over it. The submenus expand horizontally upon mouse hover. Exactly one menu item can be selected as no radio buttons or check boxes are contained in the menu. This particular menu does not require DB access to populate its children. It works sort of like Velocity CoolMenus4 from the Struts-Menu demos.

Comment: what libraries does it have to be compatible to? Is it okay to suggest alternatives to struts altogether (with their own menu library)?

Comment: @Angelo Neuschitzer For my use case that I faced, I was designing a Struts2 application (too late to change).  So I needed something which could work well with Struts2.